# Jquery find or children with all occurrences of elements with a class , and skipping a middle level and restricted to their level

Tags: html, find, jquery-selectors, children

I need help getting the right selectors and restrictions to retrieve child elements at a certain level given the beneath bit of HTML.

I have the first element which is the li at the top.

I need to get it's children under the child ul, which have class "subtree-checkbox".
An image is attached for clarity.
Many thanks.

```
<li class="green checked" style="color: yellow; border: 2px solid yellow;">
<span class="accordion-heading" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" data-target="#Smenu_0_1__1">
    <span id="sp_SM_0_1" class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_0_1" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_0_1" type="checkbox" iid="1" value="false" style="display: none;"></span>
    Users
</span>
<ul class="nav nav-list collapse in" id="Smenu_0_1__1" style="padding-left: 60px;" aria-expanded="true">
    <li>
        <span class="accordion-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Smenu_0_1__10" aria-expanded="true">
            <span id="sp_SM_0_1_1" class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled grey checked" style="color: yellow; border: 2px solid yellow;"><input name="SM_0_1_1" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_0_1_1" type="checkbox" iid="2" value="false" style="display: none;"></span>
            new subby tst3
        </span>
        <ul class="nav nav-list collapse in" id="Smenu_0_1__10" aria-expanded="true" style="padding-left: 20px;">
            <li>
            </li>

            <li>
            </li>

            <li>
            </li>

            <li>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried this but obviously fails.

```
    var kiddieEls = $(SpanParent).children("input[type=checkbox]");
```

and this

```
    var kiddieEls =$(SpanParent).children('ul').find("subtree-checkbox:first-child");
```

How would i get one or all the children elements at that level?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, probably not near the best way, but it works.

I have the Parent Li in a 'LiParent', which is my starting point.

```
//  finds the ULs under this li element
var childUL = $(LiParent).children('ul .nav-list');

// gets the first level of children (li's)
var FirstLi = $(childUL).children().first();

//use that first child to find the required spans
var ChkBoxSpanS_ToAccumulate = $(SpanAccordionchild).children('span').first()
```